# Detect if interface method is the default one before API level 24

Tags: java, android

According to [Java 8 support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) on Android:

- *Default* and static interface methods - is available on any version of Android.
- `java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault()` - is available on `API level 24`.

Question: is it possible thru reflection or somehow else to detect if interface method is *default*?

Scope: I need to have figure-out if interface is "functional interface" in order to create proxy later if it's the case.

Comment: Baseline: you are looking for a possibility to determin whether an interface has exactly one abstract/unimplemented method?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let say I have method called ".call()", which does some  things with params and then calls method called ".callInner()". Thus I expect my proxy to be called only for the "unimplemented" method.